# JavaScript - Update value of Instance in Class after changing the called parameters

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm completely new to JS and OOPS ( and also not sure about the title ).

In the snippet below, containing Car class as well as its instance. I want to ask if there is a way to update the instance, after changing one of the class parameters. For Example, I want the expected output to the updated value i.e, NewEagl after changing the parameters.
The code below returns ("Eagle") both the times.

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}

var mak = 'Eagle'
const car1 = new Car(mak, 'Talon TSi', 1993);

console.log(car1.make);
// output: "Eagle"
function changemak() {
    mak = 'NewEagl';
}

changemak();
console.log(car1.make);
// Expected output: "NewEagl"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign a variable to a property, it just copies the value, it doesn't make a permanent link between the variable and the property. So changing `mak` doesn't change `car1.make`.

`changemak` needs to take the `Car` as a parameter, and set the property of it.

```
function changemak(car) {
    car.make = 'NewEagl';
}
changemak(car1);
```

Comment: Thanks ! for the quick reply.

Comment: SelectPure(".multi-select-custom", {
    options: options,
    value: [],
    multiple: true,
    inlineIcon: customIcon,
    onChange: value => {
      document.getElementById('choices').value = value;
    },} I have doubt as in the above instance of class, how do I re-instantiate the class if options field of second parameter is changed ( options is global variable here )

Comment: Check the documentation of the widget to see how you do it. There might be a method to change the options, or you just re-run the initialization function. This is not related to your original question.

Comment: Yeah I got it.  I just started learning oops and got confused. Thanks .....